# Nokogiri parsing encoded URL string

Tags: ruby, xml, character-encoding, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse external XML documents.  One of the files I am dealing with contains URLs that have been incorrectly encoded using HTML encoding and in addition are not within `CDATA` tags:

The XML node is as follows:

```
<JobUrl>https://chk.tbe.taleo.net/chk01/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=JUSTENERGY&amp;cws=1&amp;rid=2621</JobUrl>
```

When the document has been parsed by Nokogiri the result is:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdbd79a4384 name="JobUrl" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdbd79a1fa8 "https://chk.tbe.taleo.net/chk01/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=JUSTENERGYcws=1rid=2482">]>
```

Note the missing "&".

Is there a way for Nokogiri to properly translate this to

```
https://chk.tbe.taleo.net/chk01/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=JUSTENERGY&cws=1&rid=2621
```

or do I need to ask the document maintainer to remove the encoding and use CDATA tags?

I am using OpenURI to pull the full XML document down:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'    
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url)).remove_namespaces!
```

Comment: I get the ampersands included when I try to reproduce this. Can you include your actual code?

Comment: Thanks @matt I updated to hopefully shed some more light.

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't adequately demonstrate the problem you're having, but taking a guess, it looks like you're not using Nokogiri correctly. Consider this code, which is where I'd start:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<JobUrl>https://foo.bar/file.jsp?org=JE&amp;cws=1&amp;rid=2621</JobUrl>')

doc.at('JobUrl').text
# => "https://foo.bar/file.jsp?org=JE&cws=1&rid=2621"

doc.at('JobUrl').content
# => "https://foo.bar/file.jsp?org=JE&cws=1&rid=2621"
```

The resulting text appears to be what a proper URL is, after having the entities decoded. If you need them encoded then reencode them prior to using them.